# Typescript Error Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, localforage

Typescript Error

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
>   'driver' must be of type 'string | string[]', but here has type
>   'string | LocalForageDriver | LocalForageDriver[]'.
>
> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
>   'version' must be of type 'number', but here has type 'string'.

```
package.json

{
  "name": "Test",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "localforage-cordovasqlitedriver": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "appture2: An Ionic project"
}
```

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
>   '_support' must be of type 'boolean | LocalForageDriverSupportFunc',
>   but here has type 'boolean | Promise'.

Answer (score 0):

from your package.json i can see you set the

```
"cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "", //< -- string
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
```

Try instead this:

```
"cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": 1, //<--set as number
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
```

Hope it heelps you!

Comment: its getting error on ionic serve

node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts file

Comment: try to delete you node_modules .folder .. and then try a npm ci

Comment: change @ionic/storage version 2.0 solve this issue.